# Excluding several pages from styling by CSS

Tags: css

I have some style that is supposed to be applied on all pages except three of them. It work fine for one page when I use

```
body:not(.home) #menu-footer{
    color:green;
}
```

but how does it work for my other two pages (page-id-6 and page-id-7)? I tried this

```
body:not(.home) #menu-footer, body:not(.page-id-6) #menu-footer, body:not(.page-id-7) #menu-footer{
    color:green;
}
```

but its not working.

Comment: I think this will work better: `body:not(.home, .page-id-6, .page-id-6) #menu-footer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body:not(.home) #menu-footer,
body:not(.page-id-6) #menu-footer,
body:not(.page-id-7) #menu-footer { … }
```

This doesn’t work, because when the body *does* have the class `page-id-6`, the other parts become true - you have a body that matches `body:not(.home)` now*, so the first part of this selector applies.

Apply all your “nots” at the same time instead:

```
body:not(.home):not(.page-id-6):not(.page-id-7) #menu-footer
```

This only applies when the body has *neither* of those three classes.

---

* Assuming of course, that only one of those classes is ever going to be set, but I guess that can be implied from the context of your question here.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a class for those pages you want to apply same styling to, in this case page ids 6 & 7, then apply a style. Here I'm using common_pages;

```
common_pages{
   Color: green;
}
```

Comment: I can't edit the body classes, I am using Wordpress.